# No qualifying bean of type LockProvider while configuring Spring Scheduler with Shedlock

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-scheduled, shedlock

I am trying to integrate Shedlock to make scheduled job on my Spring boot application run seamlessly in multi pod deployments.

Main class is as follows:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@EnableSchedulerLock(defaultLockAtMostFor = "60m", defaultLockAtLeastFor = "15m")
@ComponentScan
public class MyService {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SconeApp.run(MyService.class, args);
  }
}
```

For configuring scheduler with Shedlock added following class:

```
import com.salesforce.tm.scheduler.MyScheduler;
import net.javacrumbs.shedlock.core.LockProvider;
import net.javacrumbs.shedlock.provider.jdbctemplate.JdbcTemplateLockProvider;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

@Configuration
public class LockProviderConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public LockProvider lockProvider(MyDbDataSource dataSource) {
    return new JdbcTemplateLockProvider(
        JdbcTemplateLockProvider.Configuration.builder()
            .withJdbcTemplate(new JdbcTemplate(dataSource))
            .build()
    );
  }

  @Bean
  public MyScheduler myScheduler(LockProvider lockProvider) {
    return new MyScheduler();
  }
}
```

MyDbDataSource class is as follows:

```
@Component
public class MyDbDataSource implements InitializingBean {

  public TcDbDataSource(..) {
    super();
    ...
  }

  @Override
  public void afterPropertiesSet() {
     ...
  }
}
```

My scheduler class is as follows:

```
public class MyScheduler {

  @Scheduled(cron = "*/1 * * * * *")
  @SchedulerLock(name = "myTask",
      lockAtMostFor = "${scheduling.my-job.lock-at-most}",
      lockAtLeastFor = "${scheduling.my-joblock-at-least}")
  public void myCronJob() throws InterruptedException {
    LockAssert.assertLocked();
    while(true) {
      System.out.println("Test");
      Thread.sleep(1000L);
    }
  }
}
```

While launching the application, I am getting following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'net.javacrumbs.shedlock.core.LockProvider' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1714)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1270)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1224)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:884)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:788)
```

I cannot understand what I am missing here.

Comment: can you please show your import statements for

`@Bean public LockProvider lockProvider(MyDbDataSource dataSource) {`

Comment: @JAsgarov update OP accordingly.

Comment: could it be that your `@ComponentScan` doesn't pick up your `@Configuration` because your `MyService` class is in a lower level directory? (btw you don't need extra `@ComponentScan` because `@SpringBootApplication` includes component scan

Comment: @JAsgarov I get what you are telling. But everything was working fine until I added this Scheduler related configs. So I guess I messed up with Scheduling related annotations.

Answer (score 5):

try redefining your LockProvider bean

```
@Bean
public LockProvider lockProvider(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new JdbcTemplateLockProvider(dataSource);
}
```

like in this guide https://www.baeldung.com/shedlock-spring

Comment: Adding more on this answer, if your table name is defined under schema like XYZ, then you can rewrite your return statement as: 
`return new JdbcTemplateLockProvider(dataSource, "XYZ.SHEDLOCK");`